# How to replace a value in json file with a new value using a variable

Tags: bash, jq

I want to replace the value for `id` with a new one.
I have the following json file.

```
 [
  {
    "adminConsentDescription": "default",
    "adminConsentDisplayName": "default",
    "id": "5ad89ced-56a1-2222-8200-1ded5129d788",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "type": "User",
    "userConsentDescription": null,
    "userConsentDisplayName": null,
    "value": "default"
  }
]
```

And want to replace it with the variable app_id `app_id=6e663913-0000-3456-c083e40fbc99`
and the output should be

```
[
  {
    "adminConsentDescription": "default",
    "adminConsentDisplayName": "default",
    "id": "6e663913-0000-3456-c083e40fbc99",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "type": "User",
    "userConsentDescription": null,
    "userConsentDisplayName": null,
    "value": "default"
  }
]
```

I tried and came to a point where I was able to extract the value with Jq

defined the variable first

App_id=6e663913-0000-3456-c083e40fbc99

```
jq --argjson id $app_id 'map(."id" = $app_id)' oauth2-permissions.json
```

Tried couple of other permutations but could not replace with a variable. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```bash
APP_ID=6e663913-0000-3456-c083e40fbc99
jq --arg app_id "$APP_ID" '.[].id = $app_id' oauth2-permissions.json
```